Hashing all files in a directory
Could one get access to the start and stop addresses of every file in a directory from the file allocation table and stream all of those bytes into a hashing algorithm without individually opening and closing each file.
For constraints assume modern operating systems (Windows 11, MacOS [whatever is current], Ubuntu 24.04) and an application running in user space, possibly with sudo/admin.
Theoretically I know all of the bytes exist on the disk, but I'm not sure if the process of accessing raw data on a HDD (or SSD) is feasible in 2024, given modern file allocation and compression and encryption, etc.
The motivation is specifically to make the fastest directory hashing function, so would also appreciate any thoughts on whether this is a valid approach.

With POSIXy systems, one of the abstractions is access to storage devices as a file, permission suitably restricted.
